# What is the name of the character that designates literals when lexing an input sequence?

Tags: parsing, grammar, lexer

I want to know what is the *'terminology name'* of the character that designates a start of a literal in a lexing process.

For example:

- a string starts and ends with an **"** character.
- a regular expression literal - with an **/** character.

Comment: you have 2 spelling mistakes in your title...

Comment: Mitch: Why don't you just fix the spelling for him? I'm guessing the poster is Bulgarian, and is unable to spot misspellings as easily as you or I.

Comment: @Mitch Thanks for pointing them. My browser spell-checker was not turn for the question name field which results in those mistakes. I do rely heavily on it and do not double check before posting. I will take a note.

@Gabe Thanks for fixing the mistakes. You are right that English is not my native language, but I do not have an excuse for making these mistakes. I will check twice in the future before posting :)

Comment: Are you only interested in this terminology for quoted-string like things? See discussion under "delimiters" answer by Frederic.

Comment: Yes I am. Thanks for the great comments. I will call these delimiters for lack of a better word. Actually delimiter was the name we were  going to use, but I decided to post the question here and gather community feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've always called them [delimiters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter). That's as close as a "terminology name" as I can think of.

Comment: For "simply quoted" things, delimiter might be ok, and so might "introductory quote".  But literals can be introduced by all kinds of indicators:  0xDEADBEEF is a numeric literal with a leading hint, u"ABC" is often used for Unicode strings, and DEADBEEFh is a numeric literal with a *trailing* indicator.   I don't think there's any particularly good name.

Comment: @Ira Baxter, you've used `hint` and `indicator` in your comment, and those are good names too :)

Comment: I've written *lots* of lexers (think nearly a hundred) for different programming languages.  Ultimately what distinguishes tokens isn't the "leading characters" but simply that they have non-intersecting sets of syntax.  And this goes back to abstract computer science langauge theory: what defines a "langauge" (for this discussion, a token) is abstractly just the complete set of strings that make up the langauge (token).  All that matters to distinguish one token type from another, is that the sets of abstract strings for each don't intersect. ....

Comment: continued... Most languages actually do allow such sets to intersect, and have a rule that when such intersection takes place, that the token is interpreted as being a member of just one. The classic such rule is for identifiers, typically [A-Z0-9]+ which clearly overlaps with keywords IF, GOTO, ... with the overlap rule  that if a token string can be interpreted as both an identifier and a keyword, that it should be interpreted as a keyword. No "hint" or "indicator" in this case.